# Python error - object of type 'bool' has no len() in python quiz

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I am having a bit of trouble in my python 2.7.3 code, i am making a quiz that imports a csv file with a list of keywords and definitions in it. I am importing the keywords into a list. I have the question working, but the answer to the question is not, no matter what i do, i keep getting this -

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\new work (computerscience)\computerscience\coresworkn (programs)\main program\new code modle (b).py", line 94, in <module>
    answer()
  File "G:\new work (computerscience)\computerscience\coresworkn (programs)\main program\new code modle (b).py", line 67, in answer
    cans = random.choice(answ)==question
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
`
```

i have tried many things to solve it, and i don't understand where

```
return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]
```

is coming from as it is not in my program. Please could someone tell me what i am doing wrong and how i can solve it. if you would like to see my program, i can provide the raw code if necessary.

thanks.

Comment: You know that the problem is in the line `cans = random.choice(answ)==question`, but you don't tell us what `answ` is?

Comment: `answ = random.sample(bio, 3)==[1]` there is what `answ` is, that was just the error that came up that i posted. @Penfold

Comment: That would have been useful information in the question ;) So answ is indeed boolean (either True or False) as kojiro already said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving `random.choice` a boolean argument

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choice(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```